# How to remove fragment from URI

Tags: java

I am needing advices on the URI API.

I am making the URI like this

```
new URI("http", "", "localhost", 9000, "/action", "param=1","")
res0: java.net.URI = http://@localhost:9000/action?param=1#
```

As you can see, it is putting "@" in front of localhost and also I see "#" at the end of the URI. How can I get rid of these? Why are they coming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter to that constructor of URI is the userInfo... Set it to null, rather than the empty string.

```
new URI("http", null, "localhost", 9000, "/action", "param=1", null)
```

Comment: maybe nulling the last attr as well would solve the # issue?

Comment: Yes I tried this advices and you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the userInfo and the fragment which are correctly separated by '@' and '#' respectively.

```
URI u = new URI("https", null, "localhost", 8080, "/myapi", "q=all", null);
System.out.print(u);
```

gives

```
https://localhost:8080/myapi?q=all
```